# .NET SQL Server Update Trigger

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I'm updating a SQL Server table (say table1) through .NET Entity Framework. table1 has got an update trigger defined which updates data on table2. Then upon save changes, an SSRS report gets generated which uses updated data from table2. 
All this looks good and works fine. 
But, once in a while in deployed application, I see that the generated report gets table2 values those were before trigger execution.
So far it's my understanding that triggers are synchronous, hence couldn't comprehend the reason behind this timing issue. Also appreciate if you have any remedy suggestions.
Using .NET Framework 4.6, SQL Server 2014

Comment: Are you using the NOLOCK hint? This is pretty sparse on details here so mostly we are left guessing.

Comment: @SeanLange, I'm not using NOLOCK hint when retrieving data for report. As I was calling report after saving changes shouldn't it be fine without using NOLOCK hint? Sorry, the question is pretty high level as I just wanna layout sequence of operations in simple way to start with.

Comment: You definitely don't want NOLOCK. I was hoping it would be that simple but alas. Are you running the report in the trigger or in your code? Are you 100% percent you don't call the report before the update has completed? Does your report query have NOLOCK hints?

Comment: I'm generating the report in my .NET code using SSRS API, which is being called upon completing saving changes on Entity Framework context object. Report query doesn't have NOLOCK hints.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the trigger fires off before the update by default.  to make it fire after you have to define the trigger with the property CREATE TRIGGER AFTER ACTION.

You could also make the proc that does does the update generate the SSRS report after the update instead of using a trigger.

Comment: There is no such thing as a before trigger in sql server. There is INSTEAD OF and AFTER only.

Comment: oh whopps.  I guess its after by default then.